Integrate MongoDB with firebase/firestore (Backend)
I'm trying to save me some work and integrate firebase/firestore funtionalities with my backend.
The idea is to take the user(in my app) and to allow him to modify his password, email, addresses, phone. I know firebase/firecloud has email-phone-validation for credentials so it sends the user a message to validate before updating his credentials (2-factor-auth). The idea is to avoid writing them myself (spare some time)
Here's the firebase.js file for configuration:
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); 
const serviceAccount = require('./firebase.json');

const config = {
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
};

const firebase = admin.apps.length ? admin.app() : admin.initializeApp(config);

module.exports = firebase;

Here's the userController.js:
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const firebase = require('../firebase');
const Cart = require('../models/cartModel');
const AppError = require('../utilities/appError');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

exports.changePassword = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { newPassword } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('+password');

  await firebase.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {
    password: newPassword,
  });

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password changed successfully' });

  next();
});

exports.changeEmail = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { newEmail } = req.body;
  const user = req.user;


  console.log(uid);

 
  await firebase.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {
    email: newEmail,
  });

  // Send email verification
  await firebase.auth().sendEmailVerification({
    email: newEmail,
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    message:
      'Email changed successfully. Please verify your new email address.',
  });

  next();
});

exports.changeAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { newAddress } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user.id;

  await firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
    address: newAddress,
  });

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Address changed successfully' });
});

exports.changePhoneNumber = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { newPhoneNumber } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user.id; 

  await firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).update({
    phoneNumber: newPhoneNumber,
  });

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Phone number changed successfully' });
});

I don't know how to continue from here. Most of the errors I get from postman (I have errorController):

{     "status": "error",     "message": "The uid must be a non-empty string with at most 128 characters." }

Or

{     "status": "error",     "message": "The uid is not defined." }


What exact line in the code you shared gives that error message? Did you check that the variables on that line all have the expected value?

Hi @FrankvanPuffelen,
userController.js: changePassword-fn-handler, once I send the HTTP request thats the outcome I receive (POST). The code is mentioned above ^
All variables are legit except the UID. I don't know how to link between the databases.
